# How to Append Laravel Collection Query Results

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have the query below:

```
$controls_checklists = collect();

foreach($active_evaluation_session->evaluation_items as $evaluation_item) {
    $controls_checklists->push(ControlsChecklist::where('macro_process_id', $evaluation_item->macro_process_id)
        ->where('process_id', 'like', $evaluation_item->process_id ? $evaluation_item->process_id : '%')
        ->where('status', 1)->get());
}

$controls_checklists->all();


return view('auto-evaluations.index', compact('controls_checklists'));
```

On my view, I have:

```
@foreach ($controls_checklists as $controls_checklist)
<tr data-entry-id="{{ $controls_checklist->id }}">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ $controls_checklist->control->control_reference }}</td>
    <td>{{ $controls_checklist->macro_process->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $controls_checklist->process->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ isset($controls_checklist->sub_process->name)? $controls_checklist->sub_process->name: '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ isset($controls_checklist->activity->name)? $controls_checklist->activity->name: '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ $controls_checklist->checkpoint }}</td>
    <td>
        @if($controls_checklist->status == 1) {{ 'Active' }} @else {{ 'In Active' }} @endif
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('controls-checklists.edit',[$controls_checklist->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">@lang('global.app_evaluate')</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

However, when I open the page I get error message

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/controls-assessment/resources/views/auto-evaluations/index.blade.php)
```

For this line

```
<tr data-entry-id="{{ $controls_checklist->id }}">
```

I think that this is not working due to the way I am attempting to merge the collections query above. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `push()` is not the way to append two collections together, use `concat()` instead.

For your code, replace `push()` with `concat()` and assign the result to the same variable.

```
$controls_checklists = $controls_checklists->concat(
    ControlsChecklist::where('macro_process_id', $evaluation_item->macro_process_id)
        ->where('process_id', 'like', $evaluation_item->process_id ? $evaluation_item->process_id : '%')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get()
);
```

Comment: Thanks @anurat-chapanond. You answers works even though my IDE give message `Expected \illuminate\Support\iterable, got \illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|Static[]` for the query inside concat. Not sure why

Comment: @FokwaBest well, Collection actually implements iterable so it's still valid. What's your IDE?

Comment: Oh I see. I am using PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

First `dd($controls_checklist);` and verify that in the place of `$controls_checklist->id` the id actually exists. If not change the foreach loop statement.

Coming to foreach loop, try using the model with join or innerjoin to manage the query result

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will not succeed on looping because your variable is returning a collection of collections.

if you want you can try this.

```
foreach($active_evaluation_session->evaluation_items as $evaluation_item) {
   $controlsChecklist = ControlsChecklist::where('macro_process_id', $evaluation_item->macro_process_id)
            ->where('process_id', 'like', $evaluation_item->process_id ? $evaluation_item->process_id : '%')
            ->where('status', 1)->get();
   foreach ($controlsChecklist as $value) {
     $controls_checklists->push($value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to collect the data in a new collection variable.

try this:

```php
$query = ControlsChecklist::query();

foreach($active_evaluation_session->evaluation_items as $evaluation_item) {
    $query->where('macro_process_id', $evaluation_item->macro_process_id)
        ->where('process_id', 'like', $evaluation_item->process_id ? $evaluation_item->process_id : '%')
        ->where('status', 1);
}

return $query->get();
```